# Eigenfunction summation

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Given that $(\psi_i)_0^{|\chi|-1}$ is an orthonormal basis in $\ell^2(\pi)$ of real eigenfunctions of $K$ where $K$ is a Markov operator, then why is $\sum_0^{|\chi|-1} \psi_i^2(x)\pi(x) = 1$?

If we were summing over $x$, then it would make sense since $\psi_i$ is of unit norm.  This time though, we're summing over $i$ so I don't see why the above still holds.  I think it's false, but I want to make sure.

And the source of this is here: [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-6/issue-3/Logarithmic-Sobolev-inequalities-for-finite-Markov-chains/10.1214/aoap/1034968224.full)

(At the end of page 702.)

I'm also stuck trying to prove corollary 2.2 in the paper, which is $$\|h_t^x-1\|_2^2 \leq \frac{1}{\pi(x)}e^{-t}+\|k_x^{[t/2]}-1\|_2^2.$$  Help would be much appreciated!

*UPDATE* I GOT IT.

However, I would still appreciate someone explaining to me why $\left\|H_t\right\|_{2\to \infty}=\sup_x h_{2t}(x,x)>1$ for all finite $t>0$, yet the limit as $t\to \infty$ is $1.$  That's unclear to me.
Also why is $\left\|H_t\right\|_{2\to q}$ decreasing with respect to $t.$  I'd especially appreciate an intuitive explanation.

Comment: What is $\pi(x)$? Could you explain your notation a bit?

Comment: It's probably the stationary distribution.

Comment: $\pi(x)$ represents the probability w.r.t the stationary distribution $\pi$ of being at state $x.$

Comment: Shouldn't $K$ be reversible for there to exist an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions?

Comment: Yep, forgot to mention that $K$ is reversible (thus self-adjoint).